# Get/Set metadata of azure files via unc

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I am accessing the azure files share via UNC. I have it mount in a windows vm and I am able to access/read files. However I also need to read and do things based on the metadata that is being set on those files.
As far I know the metadata are custom key-value pairs that can be stored on a azure file share, folder and files. A different application set it via Rest API sdks.

So, is there any way to get/set those custom metadata by mounting it in a vm?

I am using a c# program to read into the share and list files in order to find newly uploaded files. Although it works on checking last modified date, I still need to filter on a specific metadata to prevent double processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST metadata can only be accessed from REST and is not available through SMB.

If you wish you may leave your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage).  All the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.